# Symmetric Difference Inequality in a Probability Space

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let (Ω, $\mathcal B$, $P$) be a probability space with $\mathcal B$ = σ($\mathcal A$), where $\mathcal A$ is an algebra of subsets
of Ω. Show that for $B$ ∈ $\mathcal B$ and all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a set $A_\epsilon$ ∈ $\mathcal A$ such that
P($B\Delta A_\epsilon$) < $\epsilon$  and so $|P(B) − P(A_\epsilon)|$ < $\epsilon$

My attempt:

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given. Consider the countable disjoint set $ \{A_i\}_{i =1}^\infty \subseteq \mathcal A $ such that $ B \subseteq \bigcup_{i =1}^\infty A_i $ and $ P(\bigcup_{i =1}^\infty A_i) = \sum_{i =1}^\infty P( A_i) \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} + P(B) $.

Since $ P(B) \le 1 $ then $ \sum_{i =1}^\infty P( A_i) $ converges which means we can find some $ N_\epsilon \in \mathbb N $ such that for every $ n \ge N_\epsilon, \; \sum_{i =n+1}^\infty P( A_i) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \; $. Let $ A_\epsilon = \sum_{i =1}^n P( A_i) $.

\begin{align} P(B \Delta A_\epsilon) & = P(B \setminus A_\epsilon) + P(A_\epsilon \setminus B) \\\\ & \le P(\bigcup_{i=n+1}^\infty A_i) + P(\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right) \setminus B) \\\\
& \le \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty P(A_i) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i) - P(B) \\\\
& \le \epsilon  \end{align}

So suppose $ B$ and $A_\epsilon$ are disjoint. Then $|P(B)-P(A_\epsilon)| \le P(B \Delta A_\epsilon) =  P(B) + P(A_\epsilon)  < \epsilon. $

I cant figure out how to show this ineqality if $ B$ and $A_\epsilon$ are not disjoint. Also how do I show that such a such a set like $ \{A_i\}_{i =1}^\infty $ exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to consider $B$ and $A_{\epsilon}$ disjoint or not. Use the fact that
$$
C\subset D\cup (C\bigtriangleup D)
$$
The proof is as follows:
\begin{align}
D\cup (C\bigtriangleup D)&=D\cup ((C-D)\cup (D-C))
\\
&=(C\cup D)\cup (D-C)
\\
&=C\cup D\tag{$D-C\subset C\cup D$}
\\
&\supset C
\end{align}
So in this case, we have
$$
B\subset A_{\epsilon}\cup (B\bigtriangleup A_{\epsilon})
$$
And thus
$$
P(B)\leqslant P(A_{\epsilon})+P(B\bigtriangleup A_{\epsilon})\quad\text{or }\quad P(B)-P(A_{\epsilon})\leqslant P(B\bigtriangleup A_{\epsilon})
$$
Likewise
$$
A_{\epsilon}\subset B\cup (B\bigtriangleup A_{\epsilon})
$$
And
$$
P(A_{\epsilon})-P(B)\leqslant P(B\bigtriangleup A_{\epsilon})
$$
Thus
$$
|P(B)-P(A_{\epsilon})|\leqslant P(B\bigtriangleup A_{\epsilon})
$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can show the set $\{A_i\}_{i =1}^\infty \subseteq \mathcal A$ exists such that $B \subseteq \bigcup_{i =1}^\infty A_i$ and $\sum_{i =1}^\infty P( A_i) \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} + P(B)$? If we let one of the $A_i$ be $\Omega$ then we have that $B$ is contained in the union but is there any way to justify that given a $\epsilon$ we can find $\{A_i\}_{i =1}^\infty$ that satisfies $\sum_{i =1}^\infty P( A_i) \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} + P(B)$?

Comment: This is not a trivial question at all. Read the Theorem 6 on page 261 in Introductory Real Analysis by Kolmogroff and Fomin, which is the best proof to my knowledge. Royden also proves it but not very rigorous in my opionion, but could be good enough. I'd appreciated if you can accept it as answer.

Comment: Stein has a good proof of this as well. But the proofs in the real analysis text books differ in that in this question we are covering our measurable set of finite measure, $ B \in \mathcal B $, with sets $ A_i \in \mathcal A $ where in the real analysis textbooks we are covering our measurable set of finite measure, $ E $, with closed cubes $ Q_i $. So since E is measurable there exists a countable collection of closed cubes so that  $ m(E) + \epsilon \ge \cup_{i=1}^\infty Q_i $. But I don't see how we have same control over the sets $ A_i $ to get $m(B) + \epsilon \ge \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i $

Comment: Note that $A_i$ is in the algebra and so it is the countable union of open cubes.

Answer (score 1):

Since $B\cup (A_\epsilon\setminus B) =(B\setminus A_\epsilon)\cup A_\epsilon$, we have
$$
P(B)+P(A_\epsilon\setminus B)=P(B\setminus A_\epsilon)+P(A_\epsilon)
$$
and so
$$
P(B)-P(A_\epsilon)=P(B\setminus A_\epsilon)-P(A_\epsilon\setminus B).
$$
Therefore,
$$
|P(B)-P(A_\epsilon)|\le P(B\setminus A_\epsilon)+P(A_\epsilon\setminus B)=P(B\Delta A_\epsilon).
$$